# Bokeh add label to second axis on the right

Tags: bokeh

I am creating a bar chart using [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org), and I want to display 2 independent sets of data. I have [added another y-axis to the right side of my plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914348/3585557) using the following

```
bar2.extra_y_ranges = {"Mtons": Range1d(start=0, end=2000)}
bar2.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Mtons"), 'right')
```

How do I add a label for the second axis?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`LinearAxis` has a parameter [`axis_label`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html).  This can be set by editing the call to `LinearAxis` as follows:

```
bar2.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Mtons", axis_label="Mt CO2e"), 'right')
```