# Bokeh, combination of bar and line chart

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to plot a line on top of a bar chart within bokeh. I have tried:

```
p1 = figure()...

p1.renderer.append(Bar(...))
p1.renderer.append(Line(...))

show(p1)
```

So far I had no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combination of two or more graphs in one plot in Bokeh is possible using the [Basic Glyphs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html).

For your question we can use line and rect.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.ranges import Range1d
import numpy


output_file("line_bar.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

# add a line renderer
p.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 6, 4, 5], line_width=2)

# setting bar values
h = numpy.array([2, 8, 5, 10, 7])

# Correcting the bottom position of the bars to be on the 0 line.
adj_h = h/2

# add bar renderer
p.rect(x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], y=adj_h, width=0.4, height=h, color="#CAB2D6")

# Setting the y  axis range   
p.y_range = Range1d(0, 12)

p.title = "Line and Bar"

show(p)
```

And the plot we get:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Piggybacking on @tomaskazemekas: While it's probably best to avoid mixing plotting and chart levels within Bokeh, it is possible to modify a high-level chart object using [`add_glyph`](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.1/docs/reference/models/plots.html#bokeh.models.plots.Plot.add_glyph):

```py
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.ranges import Range1d

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Line as Line_glyph

import numpy as np

# create dummy data
df = dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[6, 7, 6, 4, 5],
    h=[2, 8, 5, 10, 7]
)

# create high-level bar chart
p = Bar(data=df, label='x', values='h', color='dodgerblue', title="Bar and Line Plot",
        legend=False, plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

# create source data object from data
source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

# create a line glyph object which references columns from source data
glyph = Line_glyph(x='x', y='y', line_color='grey', line_width=2)

# add the glyph to the chart
p.add_glyph(source, glyph)

# Setting the y  axis range   
p.y_range = Range1d(0, 12)

output_file("line_bar.html")

show(p)
```

Results in a similar plot:
[Bar and Line Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBG3D.png)

Comment: `from bokeh.models.glyphs import Line as Line_glyph` why make the alias longer than the original name.... -_-

Comment: Thanks for the question. It avoids a collision with `from bokeh.charts import Line` which is often imported for other plots in the same analysis. Also to clearly distinguish the glyph object from the chart object in the code.