# How to add multiple Y axis with chartify to draw Elbow curves

Tags: python, data-visualization, unsupervised-learning, chartify

I'd like to create a line chart but with 2 distinct Y axis with a different scale to replace this piece of code which generates 2 charts:

```
ch = chartify.Chart(blank_labels=True)
ch.set_title("Elbow method with Euclidian distance")
ch.plot.line(
    data_frame=df_elbow,
    x_column='K',
    y_column='Distortion',
    line_width=1)
ch.show()

ch = chartify.Chart(blank_labels=True)
ch.set_title("Elbow method with sum of squared errors")
ch.plot.line(
    data_frame=df_elbow,
    x_column='K',
    y_column='SSE',
    line_width=1)
ch.show()
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
2nd y-axis plots have been implemented! See `chartify.examples.chart_second_axis()`

Old answer:
At the moment there isn't support for 2nd y-axis plots, but I'll add in an [issue](https://github.com/spotify/chartify/issues/36) for it. Thanks for the suggestion!

For now I'd suggest falling back on Bokeh. [See an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199665/one-chart-with-two-different-y-axis-ranges-in-bokeh).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, here is what I did using the Bokeh figure while waiting for chartify to support 2 axis:

```
import bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d

ch = chartify.Chart(blank_labels=True)
ch.set_title("Elbow method to find optimal K")
ch.set_subtitle("Euclidian distance (Blue) and sum of squared errors (Red)")

ch.figure.y_range = Range1d(5, 14)
ch.figure.line(x=df_elbow['K'], y=df_elbow['Distortion'], line_width=1, line_color="Blue")
ch.figure.extra_y_ranges = {"sum": Range1d(start=200000, end=1200000)}
ch.figure.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="sum"), 'right')
ch.figure.line(x=df_elbow['K'], y=df_elbow['SSE'], line_width=1, y_range_name='sum', line_color="Red")
ch.show()
```